# Where can I use the JS Switch case statement to convert these multiple If/Else statements?

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, switch-statement

Hello and thank you in advance for any assistance or insight.

I have a Space Battle game I'm working on and I want to know if there is a way to use a JavaScript SWITCH case statement to replace the many If/Else statements I have in my code.
I don't know what line I would begin at for the `switch (expression)`. 
Would a `switch (expression)` be appropriate for this program?

```
// Battle Function = Set up a function that "Holds" the battle

let shipsBattle = (ship1, ship2) => {

  let ships = [ship1, ship2]; // put the ships into an array
  let attack = false;
  let attacking = 0;
  let beingAttacked = 1;
  let temp;
  console.log("%c Attack Begins =================", "font-size: 30px");
  while (ships[beingAttacked].hull > 0) { //While the hull is greater than 0...Keep attacking


    // Attacking Sequence

    if (ships[beingAttacked].hull > 0) {

      console.log("\n"); // Console log the attack information
      console.log(
        `%c ${ships[attacking].name} attacked ${ships[beingAttacked].name}`,
        "color: purple; border: 1px solid grey; font-size: 18px;"
      );

      attack = ships[attacking].attack(); // Generate the attack on the enemy ship
      if (attack === true) {
        ships[beingAttacked].hull -= ships[attacking].firePower; //Increase Fire power
        console.log(
          `%c Attack Successful! ${ships[beingAttacked].name} Hull: ${ships[beingAttacked].hull}`,
          "color: green; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px;"
        );
      } else {
        console.log(
          `%c Attack Unsuccessful! ${ships[beingAttacked].name} Hull: ${ships[beingAttacked].hull}`,
          "color: red; font-size: 16px;"
        );
      }

      if (ships[beingAttacked].hull <= 0) { // Check if the ship being attacked is still alive
        console.log(
          `%c ${ships[beingAttacked].name} has been destroyed`,
          "color: red; border: 1px solid grey; font-size: 16px;"
        );
        if (ships[beingAttacked] === ussSchwartz) {

          alert("Game Over!!!"); //If the USS Ship is being attacked alert player Game is Over
        } else if (
          ships[beingAttacked].name === alienShips[alienShips.length - 1].name
        ) {
          alert(
            `%c ${ships[beingAttacked].name} destroyed!\nAlien fleet has been destroyed!\nyou have been victorious`,
            "color: green;"
          );
        } //If USS destroys alien fleet, then alert player of victory
        else {
          game.userResponse = prompt(
            `${alienShips[game.targetShip].name} destroyed!!\n${
              ussSchwartz.name
            } Hull: ${
              ussSchwartz.hull
            }\nWould you like to ATTACK the next ship or RETREAT from battle?`,
            ""
          );
          game.targetShip += 1; //PROMPT PLAYER IF THEY WANT TO CONTINUE OR RETREAT
          checkUserPrompt();
          return;
        }
      } else {

        temp = attacking; // Change the attacking/attacked ships
        attacking = beingAttacked;
        beingAttacked = temp;
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: `switch` is only appropriate if you're doing equality comparisons of the same expression to different values. It's not useful for greater/less than comparisons, or testing different expressions. I don't see anything here that could be replaced with a switch.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are checking `ships[beingAttacked].hull > 0` and then doing some calculations of true and false.
After that you are updating `ships[beingAttacked]` and doing comparisons on `ships[beingAttacked].hull < 0`

As such switch doesn't look appropriate as it is usually used when we have something defined and we are not doing different comparisons in each else if.

I guess, what you are trying to do is doing a code cleanup. I would suggest you:

- Create flow chart of your use cases and try to identify the common code. or a logic that can be reused.
- move that code in separate functions, this will increase the readability and re utilization of code.